# what's difference between Object.assign() and '= assign' to realize shallow copy in array or object?

Tags: javascript

To realize shallow copy in object in below code, but the different outputs confuse me:

**Object.assign:**

```
var obj = {
  name: 'wsscat',
  age: 0,
  add: {
    a: 'beijing'
  }
}
var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj);
obj2.age = 18;
obj2.add.a = 'shanghai';
console.log(obj)
console.log(obj2)
```

output:

```
{ name: 'wsscat', age: 0, add: { a: 'shanghai' } }
{ name: 'wsscat', age: 18, add: { a: 'shanghai' } }
```

while use **= "assign"** to realize shallow copy:

```
var obj = {
  name: 'wsscat',
  age: 0,
  add: {
    a: 'beijing'
  }
}
// var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj);
var obj2 = obj;
obj2.age = 18;
obj2.add.a = 'shanghai';
console.log(obj)
console.log(obj2)
```

output:

```
{ name: 'wsscat', age: 18, add: { a: 'shanghai' } }
{ name: 'wsscat', age: 18, add: { a: 'shanghai' } }
```

Comment: so sorry .i do meant 'shallow copy', not 'shadow copy'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you meant 'shallow copy', not 'shadow copy', so I will reference to the former in my answer.

By using assignment operator `=` you just copy reference, so `obj2` points to the same object as `obj`, so changing property is reflected on both.

The way you used `Object.assign`, creates shallow clone by copying all own properties from source object `obj` to target object (empty) which is then assigned to variable `obj2`.

Primitive data types (null, undefined, String, Number, Boolean) are copied by value, so keys `name` and `age` on both objects contain different values in memory). Objects types (Object, Arrray, Function) are copied by reference, so object under `add` property is shared between both `obj` and `obj2`. Any change in `obj2.add.a` will be reflected on `obj.add.a`.

Take a look at polyfill implementation of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assigne/

EDIT: Another link with polyfill implementation: https://gist.github.com/spiralx/68cf40d7010d829340cb

EDIT2: Clarified difference between copying primitive types and objects.

Comment: the mozilla url can't open in china,  please have a check

Comment: I have included another link

Comment: let me know if you need more clarification

Answer (score 0):

Well answered question from **Smyk** but i want to mention a simple thing.

as he mentioned :

- first attempt was a shallow copy of an object which is a good way to avoid pointing to the same reference with flat objects (not nested).
- second attempt clearly was pointing to a reference (Array and Object are passing the reference of the variable).

More about that :

there is a problem with shallow copy of objects, because nested object/array is a reference again so in order to fix this, you may have heard about **deep copy** which is a way to allocate a separate memory location/address for the new object.

an example for that :

```
 var student1 ={ 
name : "Ahmed",
company : "Tech",
address: {
city: "Tokyo"
}
}

var student2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(student1))

student1.address.city = "Erbil";

console.log(student1.address.city); // output: Erbil
console.log(student2.address.city); // output: Tokyo
```

More information, here's [a link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-javascript/?ref=lbp)
also to go in depth read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript/)